# Nginx as a reverse proxy to hide HLS origin servers

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, reverse-proxy, http-live-streaming

I'm no nginx professional or amateur for that mater, just know how to google a lot and I need help finishing of a reverse proxy.

What I currently have a main server that handles connections which then hands the client to one of 8 backend servers that deliver the stream in either TS or HLS. I want to put a proxy at the front that acts as the main server but also delivers the stream (like an edge server i guess, but no caching) so that the origin servers are hidden.

I have got it to work with TS, but I can't for the life of me workout how to get it to work with HLS no matter how much I packet capture. It pulls the manifest fine but unlike with TS it isn't pulling the segments from the origin servers.

Here is the code I've done so far (could probably be cleaner but this was all done with google)

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name proxy_IP_here;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;

location ~ .(m3u8|mpd)$ {
proxy_pass backend_IP_for_Main;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
}

}
location / {
proxy_pass backend_IP_for_Main;
sub_filter 'dns_i_have_it_fildering_here' 'proxy_IP_here';
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types text/javascript application/json;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
}
location @handle_redirects {
set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
}
}
```

If I remove
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
that from the .mm3u8 location block HLS will work but will be delivered directly by the origin server to the end client and not through the proxy.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.